# Ordering Array of dates javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of dates $myArray

```
(2012-09-31,1999-01-23,2018-08-29,1808-04-20,2017-11-05,1001-10-01,)
```

I want to list these dates in most current to oldest, i am using a function

```
function myFunction() {
myArray.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
}
```

The above function does not seem to order the array in any particular way.

Comment: You should make `new Date()` out of your strings

Comment: b/c javasciprt don't understand your string as date, see [sort-javascript-object-array-by-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Comment: We can't help you based on what's in the question, as we have no idea what's in your array. Date instances? Strings? If it were Date instances, `b-a` would work, so...

Comment: @Rory, your deleted answer was correct. I think the commenter was omitting `new` from the `Date` calls, which would cause a different result.

Comment: @spanky you could be correct, although I think your approach of using `localeCompare()` is better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sort()` without any parameters as it will order it alphabetically which work with this time format and then reverse it :

```js
var list = ['2012-09-31', '1999-01-23', '2018-08-29' , '1808-04-20', '2017-11-05', '1001-10-01'];

console.log(list.sort().reverse());
```

Comment: I'm so accustomed to using `.localeCompare()` that I forget the default `.sort()` is alphabetical. Using `.sort()` alone here is nicer.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, you can actually use [`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to do the comparison.

The reason is that your date strings are formatted to be most general to most specific, and are all the same length.

```js
var myArray = ['2012-09-31', '1999-01-23', '2018-08-29', '1808-04-20', '2017-11-05', '1001-10-01'];

function myFunction() {
  myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.localeCompare(a);
  });
}

myFunction();

console.log(myArray);
```

This would not work if the leading `0` on a month or day could be removed, or if the format was for example `yyyy-dd-mm` or `mm-dd-yyyy`.